# How to detect changes between two usercontrols?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a main window that contains two usercontrols.
The first usercontrol have a tabcontrol.How can I notify the second usercontrol when a tabitem is selected in the first usercontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MVVM approach, you'll probably have bound `SelectedIndex` of your `TabControl` to a ViewModel property. In that case your second usercontrol will bind to the same (or some other) property of the ViewModel and will be notified through standard notification mechanisms (such as `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyProperty` etc.).

In case, you are not using ViewModels and coding directly behind your Window, you can listen to `SelectionChanged` event and update your second usercontrol therein.

Comment: @IsmailDiari: The green tick mark on the left also works like a charm. Try it! :)

Comment: Done,it's really so :)